# Javascript click function not reacting in proper parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript that animates a div into a parent div.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var $righty = $(this).next();
        $righty.animate({
            right: parseInt($righty.css('right'),10) == 0 ?
            -$righty.outerWidth() :
            0
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="home" class="page">                
        <div id="page1">                
            <a href="#">Inside Div</a>
        </div>

        <a href="#">Outside Div</a>

        <div id="page2" class="page">
            content 
        </div>                     
   </div>
```

I want the `<a>` tag to live in the `page1` div. As of now, the Javascript only works when the `<a>` tag lives in `<div id="page1">`. I apologize if this is very basic, as I am new to Javascript. Thank you!

Comment: It's maybe not very basic, but we won't know unless you say what you want to achieve with this code.

Comment: How does your css look like. From what I remember there would need to be certain position: relative and/or absolute declarations.

Comment: See my edits below.  Still not sure, but I am guessing this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selector for your a tag, instead of just a.  Like a class or an id.   You don't want this to happen to *every single a tag*, right?

Also, righty is getting NEXT...well, there's nothing next to the a tag you want to hit.

You want to do $(this).parent().next(); - no, see edit below.  I am guessing, because you never told us what you wanted, exactly.

EDIT: This may not help at all.  Just know that you can't have an a tag in a div, and call .next() - it has no siblings.  .next() hits the next sibling.  Not as it appears visually on the page, but as it exists in the DOM tree....you need to have a sibling in the div for the a tag to grab with .next().....you don't.  Does that make sense?  What exactly are you trying to animate?

EDIT EDIT: Tell me the id or class of the tag you want animated when a given a tag with a given class or id is clicked, and I'll show you how to do it.

EDIT EDIT EDIT: If you just want to make page2 animate when page1 > a is clicked, do this:

```
$('#page1 a').click(function(){ $('#page2').animate(...put animation stuff here...) });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The "this" statement was confusing me. I just replaced it with the ID selector and all is well! I appreciate it greatly!